# publish TypeScript source files to npm, not compiled Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I am writing a library in Typescript and I want its users to be able access the source code. How to publish it to npm in original Typescript format?

Btw, why does [the official TypeScript Publishing guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) only publishes bundling of declaration files with the compiled .js files, no inclusion of .ts files.

Comment: Apologies as this does not specifically answers your question, but I hope i provide a helpful solution. For publishing of source code would it not be best to use a version control system like github or bitbucket to allow others to view it? Since npm is more designed for the installation of packages rather than reviewing the code or changes made to it? You could also link to the compiled npm package on whatever version control platform you prefer for users to install.

Comment: npm also has version control.

Comment: Then why do people bother adding projects that can be installed from npm to github? As i said it's Node Package Manager people will mainly use it as such.